# Spilled coffee on laptop

Tags: power-supply, hard-drive

Here is the story:

When I woke up, I started my PC and went in the bathroom... when i came back i noticed that my keyboard is spilled with coffee and my laptop is turned off, I quickly wiped the coffee and tried to turn on the laptop, but it couldn't start. I pushed the button a little longer, than my laptop started for a sec and turned off again. I open the keyboard and noticed that there is coffee in there too, i wiped that too.

However, I want to believe that there is nothing wrong with the hard disc, because that is my only concern. Because today is public holiday and no IT salons are working, and tomorrow is Sunday, please tell me that there is nothing wrong with my hard disk, so i can sleep normally...

Comment: The biggest danger is to the keyboard, and that may be OK if it was plain black coffee.  I've had good luck removing keyboards and washing them off when it's just coffee (immerse in water with a drop of detergent & drain several times, then rinse in distilled water several times and let dry for a week), but cola beverages have a high likelihood of causing KB damage, unless washed off immediately.  Electronics merely needs to have all traces of the liquid wiped off and then be wiped with an alcohol-dampened cloth, then allowed to dry a day or two.  Hard drive is fine unless coffee got in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say with 100% certainty in your case but I can say that in the half dozen or so computers which have come my way having had something spilled on them, the hard drive was always fine.

In the hopes of recovering your computer entirely, in the past I have been successful by removing the keys and battery and flushing the computer thoroughly with rubbing/isopropyl alcohol followed by de-ionized water. Note that this is not the same as bottled water. Grocery stores will have it labeled as "De-mineralized". Then allow it to dry thoroughly. A day in a bag packed with rice should help with this, as well as any forced air drying you can accomplish such as with canned air or a hair drier (with heat turned off).

Comment: The hard drive is so far removed from the keyboard that I'd be very very surprised if the hard drive is damaged. I dropped a small HD *into* coffee once and, after washing and letting it dry for a few days, I could still read it just fine.

Comment: @carveone Agreed. They are specifically designed to be one of the most robust pieces of equipment in the computer and when you look at the intricacies of how they work and what they do, its amazing to me they can be as cheap as they are.